# Outlining the required steps in a case type

Tags: civicase

I'm looking for a way to document the steps that a person should go through when a case of a particular type is opened.

My steps are something like this:

1. Have the person fill out this form
2. Have them sign this document
3. Send them this email.  Capture their reply.
4. Send them this other email.  Capture their reply.

I tried using the CiviCase timeline feature, but it does not seem to let me capture more than, say, "email".  I really want more detail in the step description, but I don't want to turn every single one of our template emails into a separate activity.

I would be very happy to just use repeated "email" items in the case timeline if I could put a description somewhere of what email to send, for example.  I could not find a way to do that?

The other thing I tried is just putting the task list in the description field of the case type.  That failed due to field length restrictions.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Are you already using Custom Activities with names per the above? What CMS are you using? If drupal it may make more sense to consider using Webform and Views to build the workflow

Comment: I was trying to avoid making every step in the process a custom activity.  It seems to me that if three steps in the process are "send an email" then I should not have to create three separate activity types when all I want to do is say "send email X" and "send email Y".  I would have thought that each activity in a timeline could have like a description associated to it, but it does not seem possible?  That was ultimately the genesis of this question.

Comment: I am using Drupal.  What would a View look like in this case?  I'd love to see a mockup of how this might work.  Thanks!

Comment: Hard to explain as each use case is unique but we have summary lists of Open Cases with links to a webform with case id etc, for each of the steps that needs to occur. If you have 'progressive' cases, then you could filter them in to different blocks of the view so that for each step there is only one link available to them to then whip them over to the View and fire off the email, move the case to its next status etc

Comment: You are welcome to contact me directly offline if you want a short talk through this.